# How can I rotate the camera around group of objects and not only a single one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The camera is child of one soldier only and also the target is this soldier.

[image: Camera]

And the script attached to the camera.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMove : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform target;
    public float speed = 0.1f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, new Vector3(0, 1, 0), 100 * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }


}
```

But now I want to do two things. To make the camera to rotate around the whole soldiers and not only the specific one. And also to make the camera stop slowly when it's facing the soldiers. Now the camera is behind when starting the game.

Using a bool flag if true to make the camera rotate around the soldiers until it's facing them then stop rotation and keep moving with the soldiers.

If unchecked false make the camera rotating around the solders none stop.

UPDATE what I tried so far:

This code will make it rotating around all the soldiers and it's working fine:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 0.1f;

    private List<GameObject> Soldiers = new List<GameObject>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Soldiers.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Soldier"));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RotateAround();
    }

    private void RotateAround()
    {
        transform.RotateAround(GetAverageLocationOfSoliders(), new Vector3(0, 1, 0), 100 * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }

    private Vector3 GetAverageLocationOfSoliders()
    {
        var total = new Vector3();

        foreach (var soldier in Soldiers)
            total += soldier.transform.position;

        return total / Soldiers.Count();    // Assuming Soldiers is List<Soldier>
    }
}
```

Then I tried to add a slowDown bool flag variable, But I messed it all and it's not working at all.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 0.1f;
    public bool slowDown = false;

    private List<Vector3> SoldiersPositions = new List<Vector3>();
    private List<Vector3> SoldiersFacingDirection = new List<Vector3>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        RotateAround();
    }

    private void RotateAround()
    {
        var getSoldiers = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Soldier");
        foreach (GameObject soldier in getSoldiers)
        {
            SoldiersPositions.Add(soldier.transform.position);
            SoldiersFacingDirection.Add(soldier.transform.forward);
        }

        var Center = GetAverageLocationOfSoliders();
        var FacingDirections = GetAverageFacingDirectionOfSoldiers();
        if (slowDown == true)
        {
            var D = transform.position - Center;
            var CamAngle = Vector3.Angle(D, FacingDirections);
            speed = speed - CamAngle;
        }

        transform.RotateAround(Center, new Vector3(0, 1, 0), 100 * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        SoldiersPositions = new List<Vector3>();
        SoldiersFacingDirection = new List<Vector3>();
    }

    private Vector3 GetAverageLocationOfSoliders()
    {
        var total = new Vector3();

        foreach (var soldier in SoldiersPositions)
            total += soldier;

        return total / SoldiersPositions.Count();    // Assuming Soldiers is List<Soldier>
    }

    private Vector3 GetAverageFacingDirectionOfSoldiers()
    {
        var total = new Vector3();

        foreach (var soldierfacingdir in SoldiersFacingDirection)
            total += soldierfacingdir;

        return total / SoldiersFacingDirection.Count();
    }
}
```

1. I'm not sure if the first code example only for the rotation is fine the way I wrote it. It's working but not sure if this is a good way to do the code ?
2. It seems to me that in the first code only the rotation the camera is a bit shaking or stuttering I mean the camera is not moving smooth when rotating around. It's almost hard to see in the game view in the editor but you can see it a bit in the scene view I think.
3. The reason I'm calling RotateAround(); in the Update is that the soldiers are in a move they are walking forward non stop.
4. How should I do the slowDown part ?

UPDATE 2:

This is the full coed now:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Spin")]
    public bool spin = false;
    public Vector3 Direction;
    [Range(0, 300)]
    public float speed = 10f;
    public bool randomSpeed = false;
    public bool randomDirection = false;
    [Range(0f, 100f)]
    public float timeDirChange;
    public Vector3 defaultDirection;

    [Space(5)]

    [Header("Move in circles")]
    public bool moveInCircles = true;
    public GameObject rotateAroundTarget;
    public Vector3 axis;//by which axis it will rotate. x,y or z.
    public float rotationSpeed; //or the speed of rotation.
    public float upperLimit, lowerLimit, delay;// upperLimit & lowerLimit: heighest & lowest height;
    public bool randomHeight = false;
    public bool stopRotatingWhenFacing = false;
    private float height, prevHeight, time;//height:height it is trying to reach(randomly generated); prevHeight:stores last value of height;delay in radomness;


    [Space(5)]

    [Header("Follow objects")]
    public GameObject[] objectsToFollow;
    public bool randomFollow;

    private float nextRotationTime = 0f;
    private int counter = 0;
    private List<GameObject> Soldiers = new List<GameObject>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Soldiers.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Soldier"));
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (randomSpeed)
        {
            speed = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 300);
        }

        if (spin)
        {
            if (randomDirection == false)
            {
                nextRotationTime = 0;
                timeDirChange = 0;
                Direction = defaultDirection;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Time.time > nextRotationTime)
                {
                    nextRotationTime += timeDirChange;
                    RandomDirection();
                }
            }

            transform.Rotate(Direction, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            timeDirChange = 0;
            randomDirection = false;
            randomSpeed = false;
        }

        if (moveInCircles)
        {
            MoveInCircles();
        }
    }

    private void RandomDirection()
    {
        Direction = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1));
        while (Direction == new Vector3(0, 0, 0))
        {
            counter++;
            Direction = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1));

            if (counter == 2)
            {
                Direction = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
                break;
            }
        }

        counter = 0;
    }

    private void MoveInCircles()
    {
        var F = GetAverageDirectionsOfSoliders();
        var D = transform.position - GetAverageLocationOfSoliders();
        var angle = Vector3.Angle(D, F);

        if (angle < 5f)
        {
            rotationSpeed -= 0.1f;
        }

        transform.RotateAround(GetAverageLocationOfSoliders(), axis, rotationSpeed);
        time += Time.deltaTime;
        //Sets value of 'height' randomly within 'upperLimit' & 'lowerLimit' after delay 
        if (time > delay)
        {
            prevHeight = height;
            if (randomHeight)
            {
                height = UnityEngine.Random.Range(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
            }
            time = 0;
        }

        if (randomHeight == false)
        {
            height = transform.position.y;
        }

        if (randomHeight)
        {
            //Mathf.Lerp changes height from 'prevHeight' to 'height' gradually (smooth transition)  
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, Mathf.Lerp(prevHeight, height, time), transform.position.z);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, height, transform.position.z);
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GetAverageLocationOfSoliders()
    {
        var total = new Vector3();

        foreach (var soldier in Soldiers)
        {
            total += soldier.transform.position;
        }

        return total / Soldiers.Count();    // Assuming Soldiers is List<Soldier>
    }

    private Vector3 GetAverageDirectionsOfSoliders()
    {
        var totalf = new Vector3();

        foreach (var soldier in Soldiers)
        {
            totalf += soldier.transform.forward;
        }

        return totalf / Soldiers.Count();
    }
}
```

The RotateAround part is working fine:

```
transform.RotateAround(GetAverageLocationOfSoliders(), axis, rotationSpeed);
```

But the slow down part is not working. It's not slowing down at all when the camera is facing the soldiers.

This is how I calculate the average transform.forward vector of all the soldiers:

```
private Vector3 GetAverageDirectionsOfSoliders()
    {
        var totalf = new Vector3();

        foreach (var soldier in Soldiers)
        {
            totalf += soldier.transform.forward;
        }

        return totalf / Soldiers.Count();
    }
```

Then inside the MoveInCircles method I did:

```
var F = GetAverageDirectionsOfSoliders();
        var D = transform.position - GetAverageLocationOfSoliders();
        var angle = Vector3.Angle(D, F);

        if (angle < 5f)
        {
            rotationSpeed -= 0.1f;
        }
```

But it's never getting to the line:

```
rotationSpeed -= 0.1f;
```

Answer (score 3):

To rotate around all the soldiers:

1. Get the center of the all the soldiers (sum the world position of all soldiers and divide by `N` number of soldiers)
2. Get the maximum distance of the soldiers from the center
3. Rotate the camera about the center, and ensure that it is further than the max distance from the center

To slow the camera down when facing the soldiers' front:

1. Average out the `transform.forward` vector of all the soldiers. We call this vector `F`. This is fair since all your soldiers will typically be facing in the same general direction for this request to even make sense.
2. Calculate the direction `D`, which is the direction from the soldiers' center to the camera. This is easy: `D = camera.transform.position - soldiersCenter`
3. Finally, find the acute angle between `D` and `F`, using `Vector3.Angle()`. If this angle is lower than a certain threshold, decrease the `moveSpeed` of the camera.

The actual code is easy to write, but I'll let you practice. Let me know if you need any help

Comment: I tried to do it. The first part the rotating around all the soldiers seems to be working fine. But the second part with the slowDown is messed up. Updated my question with my changes I did.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi 1. Check your `if slowDown == true` block, does it make sense? Is there anywhere where you set the `slowDown` variable to `true/false`? 2. Check your `speed = speed - camAngle` line. Is `camAngle` in degrees, will you `speed` go negative?. Fix the logic in these few lines. There are some other bad practices like instantiating lists in update blocks, but we will get to that after the logic is fixed.

Comment: I changed my script and tried again with the slow down part. Updated my question again with UPDATE 2 part. The slow down part is not working yet.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi seems like there are alot of unnecessary code now. it's simple: update loop should use a `speed` variable to update your cam position : `ds = speed * Time.deltaTime`. If u are within the angle threshold, set `speed` to a lower value. Anyways, you should try to do a general debugging yourself, find out where and what's wrong, it helps in the long run

Answer (score 1):

From the sounds of it, it seems you have it already able to orbit around a single soldier, so do to more than one, simply take the average of their locations.

**Pseudo code:**

```
transform.RotateAround(GetAverageLocationOfSoliders(), ...);
...
private static Vector3 GetAverageLocationOfSoliders
{
    var total = new Vector3();

    foreach(var soldier in Soldiers)
        total += soldier.transform.position;

    return total / Soliders.Count();    // Assuming Soldiers is List<Soldier>
}
```

Now, `Vector3` might not have stuff like `Vector3 += Vector3` or `Vector3 / int`, but if that's the case just create your own methods were you do that manually (adding `vectorA.x + vectorB.x`, and `vectorA.x / num`, etc.

As far as making the camera stop when it's in front, that's a bit trickier. You might want to do some checks first to make sure they all have the same rotation, and then check, each `Update`, if the look at rotation of the camera will point to one of the soldiers.

But, if you want it to slow down, then, instead of checking if the `lookAtRotation` can point to a soldier, check if it can point to some `offset` of the camera's rotation, like so:

**Pseudo Code:**

```
lookRotation(transform.Rotation + offset)   // Use something like this to find Soldiers[0]
```

Then, if that finds one, you can use a `Lerp` on your speed to lerp back down to a speed of 0.

You will also have to maintain a `List<Soldier>` or `Soldier[]` somehow.